# Gridview results from search or querystring?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

We have a gridview that can be edited, and this gridview is populated either by `RegularSearch()` or `SearchById(string Id)`.

This is the code:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {

            string empId = Request.QueryString["EmpId"];

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(empId))
            {
                SearchByEmpId(empId);
            }
            else
            {
                RegularSearch();
            }
        }
    }
    
    protected void GridView_EmpId_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView_EmpId.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
        string empId = Request.QueryString["empId"];
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(empId))
        {
            SearchByEmpId(empId);
        }
        else
        {
            RegularSearch();
        }
        // Start editing gridview row
    }
```

When I visit page *Employees.aspx?empId=ABC123*, `SearchByEmpId(empId)` is called and the grid will show one row. When I click "Edit", `GridView_EmpId_RowEditing` will rebind the gridview via `SearchByEmpId(empId);` and I'll edit the one row with the `empid`. That's fine.

I edit the row and then click the Search button, which will call `RegularSearch();`. The result, say 200 rows, will be displayed in the grid.

The problem is that when I edit a row, `GridView_EmpId_RowEditing` will be invoked, and it will recheck the querystring. Since `Request.QueryString["EmpId"]` will have the value from the previous request, `GridView_EmpId_RowEditing` will bind gridview using `SearchByEmpId(empId);` instead of `RegularSearch();`.

There are tons of ways of resolving the issue (a session variable or viewstate for example), but there has to be a more elegant way to fix this.

Comment: Normally, within the edit method I would get the record Id from the selected row's data and not the query parameter. That said, you could probably keep what you have using a property and binding it to the ViewState.

Comment: I suggest when you do the search or hit the search button, you wipe out the url parameters. eg: https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/177679/Removing-Deleting-Querystring-in-ASP-NET

Comment: Why close the question?

Comment: _Why close the question?_ Well, speculating as to the close voters' thinking, this jumps out to me: _there has to be a more elegant way to fix this_ - 'elegant' is a matter of opinion, not of fact. See [this Meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252854/why-doesnt-stack-overflow-allow-discussable-questions-or-questions-that-require) as to why these are discouraged. In your question you even say _There are tons of ways of resolving the issue_ - so you can just pick one, based on your own criteria.

Comment: I would ONLY use the filter on first page post-back. For any additional, use viewstate - and that could/would include row-edit event. So, on page load, move query value into viewstate and ALL filter code now works against ViewState("MyFilter"). And that means then if you hit clear, or search again, or whatever? You can clear or re-set the ViewState("MyFilter") = "" or whatever. So on first post to page (postback = false), then as you have, but MOVE the query filter value to viewstate - all additonal code can thus use viewstate - and you can clear/set/reset as you please.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably keep what you have using a property and binding it to the ViewState, ensuring you clear the property after your edit is complete.

But normally, I would get the record Id from the selected row's data and not  a ViewState mapped property.

Here's an example using ViewState...

```
// new property using the ViewState to retain the data across requests.
private string SelectedEmpId
{
    get
    {
        if(ViewState["SelectedEmpId"] == null)
        {
            ViewState["SelectedEmpId"] = string.Empty;
        }
        return ViewState["SelectedEmpId"].ToString();
    }
    set
    {
        ViewState["SelectedEmpId"] = value;
    }
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)    
    {    
        // set property from your query param
        SelectedEmpId = Request.QueryString["EmpId"];
    
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(SelectedEmpId))
        {
            SearchByEmpId(SelectedEmpId);
        }
        else
        {
            RegularSearch();
        }
    }
}

protected void GridView_EmpId_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    GridView_EmpId.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
    // we reference our ViewState mapped property
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(SelectedEmpId))
    {
        SearchByEmpId(SelectedEmpId);
    }
    else
    {
        RegularSearch();
    }
    // Start editing gridview row
    // ...

    // clear ViewState mapped property after edit is completed
    SelectedEmpId = string.Empty;
}
```